# Inserting columns in data frame Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I have a data frame that I need to be able to insert columns in using Shiny. The function filedata reads in a data set, called filedata().

```
  filedata <- reactive({
    req(input$file_selector)
    read.csv(paste0(parseDirPath(c(home = 'C:\\Users\\Ruben'), file_dir()),'\\',input$file_selector),skip=1)
  })

  output$filetable <- renderDataTable({
    filedata()
  })
```

When a user checks a box that asks if he/she wants new columns to be inserted, this code runs.  But, I am getting an "invalid (NULL) left side of assignment" error.  I have tried this in so many ways, and I cannot figure out what isn't being done incorrectly.  What is wrong with this code?

input$qc_final_cols is the checkbox id.

```
  df <- reactive({
    if (input$qc_final_cols){
      var_names = c('TA','PP','US','UD','UE','UG','UH','XR','RW','PA','TB4','TV2','TV4',
                    'TV8','TV20','TV40','MV2','MV4','MV8','MV20','MV40','VB','TA40','TA120','SD')
      output$column_names <- renderText(var_names)

      for (v in 1:length(var_names)){
        ind <- which(colnames(filedata()) == var_names[v])
        filedata() <- filedata() %>% add_column(z = NA,.after = ind)
        colnames(filedata())[ind+1] <- paste0(var_names[v],'_QC')

        filedata() <- filedata() %>% add_column(y = NA,.after = ind+1)
        colnames(filedata())[ind+2] <- paste0(var_names[v],'_Final')
      }
    }
  })

      output$filetable <- renderDataTable({
df()})
```

Comment: You cannot make assignments like `filedata() <- filedata()…` Please review reactive programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be related to `filedata() <- filedata()...` where `filedata()` is a reactive expression. That assignment may be causing an error.

Consider creating a `reactiveValues` object (`rv`) containing your data, where you can add columns, change column names, etc. Note the use of `observe` that will be used to read in the file, and assign the data frame (`df`) to `rv`.

Perhaps when the box is checked, an `observeEvent` expression will be called, and your columns can be added there. Note that you do not need to put your `output$column_names` inside this, as it will be updated automatically.

If this does not work, or doesn't help, let me know. However, it might more helpful if you are able to provide a complete but minimal reproducible example in shiny.

```
server <- function(input,output){
  
  var_names = c('TA','PP','US','UD','UE','UG','UH','XR','RW','PA','TB4','TV2','TV4',
                'TV8','TV20','TV40','MV2','MV4','MV8','MV20','MV40','VB','TA40','TA120','SD')
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(df = NULL)
  
  #This function is responsible for loading in the selected file
  observe({
    req(input$file_selector)
    rv$df <- read.csv("test9820.csv") # Simplified for testing
  })
  
  # This previews the CSV data file
  output$filetable <- renderDataTable({
    rv$df
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$qc_final_cols, {
    
    if (input$qc_final_cols){
      for (v in 1:length(var_names)){
        ind <- which(colnames(rv$df) == var_names[v])
        rv$df <- rv$df %>% 
          add_column(z = NA,.after = ind)
        colnames(rv$df)[ind+1] <- paste0(var_names[v],'_QC')
        rv$df <- rv$df %>% 
          add_column(y = NA,.after = ind+1)
        colnames(rv$df)[ind+2] <- paste0(var_names[v],'_Final')
      }
    }
  })
  
}
```

Comment: I have to say that your answer is wonderful, especially as it demonstrates how to do some reactive programming.  Thank you so much!!